# Proper way to select child class implementation conditionally?

Tags: python, inheritance

I have a database with three different tables. I have an abstract parent class interface, along with three child classes that are interfaces to each individual table. No problems so far.

I need to use each of these interfaces in different scenarios depending on which table I need to access. What is the proper way to do this in Python?

My first thought is a simple if else conditional check:

```
for name in names:
  if name == 'tbl1':
    cls = Table1Interface()
  elif name == 'tbl2':
    cls = Table2Interface()
  elif name == 'tbl3':
    cls = Table3Interface()

cls.get_value_from_table()
```

This doesn't seem like the best solution though since if I need to add a table and interface, then I need to come in here and modify this code as well. I'm trying to follow the principle of encapsulating what changes, but not sure how to apply it here.

Comment: perhaps [dependency inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion) could help?

Answer (score 0):

I would define a configuration 'mapping' dictionary, where the value is the interface function and the key is the name. Something like:

```
cls = {
    'tbl1': Table1Interface,
    'tbl2': Table2Interface,
    'tbl3': Table3Interface,
}

cls[name].get_value_from_table()
```

Modifying the  available interfaces is then just a question of updating this single dictionary.

If you can determine the interface method from the `name` (e.g. `name` is `Table1Interface`, and the classes are all attributes of 'my_class') then you can use `getattr` to access it:

```
getattr(my_class, name).get_value_from_table()
```

Or if it's a 'top-level' method, use `locals`:

```
locals()[name].get_value_from_table()
```